# Make table scrollable and fix first and last columns

Tags: css, scrollable-table

I have a table with below html

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="tblWrapper">
        <table id="tbl">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="first">header</th>
                  <th>header</th>
                  <th>header</th>...........<th class="last">header n</th>                        
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr><td class="first"></td><td></td><td></td><td class="last"></td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.wrapper{ position: relative; }
.tblWrapper{
    width: 98%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;

    #tbl{ .first, .last{ position: absolute; } }
}
```

Want I am trying to achieve here is first and last columns should be fixed and rest of the columns must be scrollable.

The issue here is fixed columns overlaps with other columns 
and other issue is entire table is not fixed in the parent div width(`having max-width: 630px;`) its spreading out.

Any working around please..........

Comment: take a look at this [article](http://anaturb.net/csstips/sheader.htm)

Comment: it's different from my case.......Farshad

Comment: try to use `<colgroup>
<col width="200px"/>
...
<col width="100px"/>
</colgroup>` right after `<table>` tag to prevent column overlaping

Comment: @user2486535 see this: http://jsfiddle.net/aw5opbkn/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `freezeHeader` (A simple jquery plugin to freeze header row in html table)
[Reference](http://laertejjunior.github.io/freezeheader/)

**HTML :**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="tblWrapper">
        <table id="tbl">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="first">header</th>
                  <th>header</th>
                  <th>header</th>
                  <th class="last">header </th>                        
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>txt</td>
                    <td>txt</td>
                    <td> txtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxt txtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxt txtxtxtxtxtxtxtxtxt</td>
                    <td>txt</td>
                </tr>

                ...
                ...
                ...

                <tr>
                    <td>txt</td>
                    <td>txt</td>
                    <td>txt</td>
                    <td>txt</td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
thead tr th {
    border-top: 1px solid #E2E6E6;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #E5E5E5;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
th {
    color: white;
    background:gray;
}
th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
}
```

**Script :**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tbl").freezeHeader();
    })
```

[**Jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cz6dnk4w/5/)

Comment: it doesn't work. I am able to fix the columns by adding position absolute. But the issue is the cells are messed up(over lapped). If we  move them by adding some positioning it will go beyond the width it has. Major thing to do is avoid overlapping and confine scrollable table to the given parent's width.

Comment: I have edited the code with using `freezeHeader` jquery plugin